# k-NN Classify in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, contour, knn

So once I extracted the image which I want from the original image as attached here,[image] I considered contour length as feature 1 and contour area as feature 2. I used sum(sum(ds)) to count the number of white pixels in binary images for each species. ds is the attached image here. And then I found the contour area, the number of pixels inscribed by the conotur by the following code.

```
area=0;
for col=1:464 
    temp=find(ds(:,col)==1);  
    if temp 
        area= area + (temp(end)-temp(1)+1); 
    end
end
area;
```

Now I should plot feature 1 vs. feature 2 plot and check if there are separable clusters and Use k-NN to classify. Can anyone tell me how to plot it, check and classify. Thanks !

Comment: Is your question how to run knn in matlab? There are lots of examples on SO and the MATLAB documentation will probably come in handy.

Comment: Hopefully you are also aware that your summation code as written might fail for two reasons: 1) `if temp` can crash or give you unwanted results, I would use `if ~isempty(temp) && length(temp)>1` or so. 2) your summation will be accurate only if the shapes are convex, but you may be content with this approximation.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot it by

```
figure(1);
plot(feature1_classA,feature2_classA,'b.');
plot(feature1_classOther,feature2_classOther,'r.');
```

then check out if the blue dots are somehow separated from the blue dots.

KNN can be easily implemented. You need some labeled data set.
When classifying a new data point, find the K closest points in the labeled data set and check from which class the majority is. Assing this label to new data point. Shouldn't be that hard to implement.